# How does docker-engine handle outgoing and incoming traffic from/to multiple containers?

Tags: docker, docker-engine

I currently have about 5 webserver running behind a reverse proxy. I would like to use an external AD to authentificate my users with the ldap protocol. would docker-engine be able to differentiate between each container by itself ?

My current understanding is that it wouldn't be possible without having a containerized directory service or without exposing different port for each container but I'm having doubts.  If I ping an external server from my container I'm able to get a reply in that same container without issue. how was the reply able to reach the proper container ?. I'm having trouble understanding how it would be different for any other protocol but then at the same time a reverse proxy is required for serving the content of multiple webservers. If anyone could make it a bit clearer for me I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a bit deeper I have found what I was looking for.

Any traffic originating from a container will get routed automatically by docker on a default network with the use of IP masquerading (similar to NAT) through iptables. The way it works is that the packets from the container will get stripped of the container IP address and replaced by the host ip address. The original ip address will be remembered until the tcp session is over. Then the traffic will go to the destination and any reply will be sent back to the host. the reply packets will get stripped of the host ip and sent to the proper container. This is why you can ping another server from a container and get a reply in that same container.

But obviously it doesn't work for incoming traffic to a webserver because the first step is the client starting a session with the webserver. That's why a reverse proxy is required.

I may be missing a few things and may be mistaken about some others but this is the general idea.

TLDR: outgoing traffic (and any reply ) will get routed automatically by docker, you will have to use a reverse proxy to route incoming traffic to multiple container.

Comment: You are exactly right. Good research and answer :)